# How do I put a scrollable div next to a non-scrollable div using CSS?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

Here is a fiddle of what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7vP/1/

Basically, I'm trying to have my content not go under the vertical navigation. I tried all the different types of `position` on `.content` and also tried `float: right;` which didn't work either.

What is the semantically correct, most efficient way, to execute this?

Current CSS:

```
div.nav {
float: left;
width: 150px;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: rgba(102, 153, 204, 1);
height: 100vh;
position: fixed; }

.content {
overflow: auto; }

.wrapper {
width: 880px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left; }
```

Current HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class='nav'>
        <ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
    </div>

    <div class='content'>
Lots of text...
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left:160px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried using `position: absolute` along with `left: 150px` but not margin. Since you got in first, I will mark it the answer.

Comment: Hey, I was first ! A minute ahead of Abel Raj :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you can set the left margin of content to 150px to off set it from the navigation

http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7vP/2/

```
.content {
    margin-left: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd give the content area a left margin of 150px (same as the width of the navigation).

I don't think there is another way using pure CSS.  Since you are using position:fixed on the navigation container, you are taking it out of the normal flow of the document.  The content container will always be positioned under it, unless you offset it to the right, by using a margin-left with a value equal to the width of the navigation container.